# Data not updating when i download a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, dto

## PDF data not dynamically changing according to inserted data

**i have an app in which I have models , controllers ,interfaces and manager classes all are in C# maybe from the code you can understand and from image i need to update data of total Provident fund  section 80C **
`

```
 public class EmplyeeSalaryDetails
 {

     public EmplyeeSalaryDetails()
     {
         SectionInvestmentList = new List<KeyValue>();
     }
     public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
     public decimal Amount { get; set; }
     public decimal PaidAmount { get; set; }
     public decimal EPFAmount { get; set; }
     public decimal EmployeeInvestmentsAmount { get; set; }

     public decimal TotalConveyanceAndHouseRent { get; set; }

     public decimal DeductedConvAndHouseAMtInPaidAmt { get; set; }
```

```
 public ActionResult DownloadEmployeeForm16(string Id, string cookieValue = "")
 {
     EmplyeeSalaryDetails empSalaryDetail = new EmplyeeSalaryDetails();

     try
     {
         Guid empId = new Guid(Id);
         empSalaryDetail = _paySalaryManager.GetEmployeeSalary(empId);
         if (empSalaryDetail.PaidAmount > 0)
         {
             return FileAsPDF(empSalaryDetail, "Partials/_EmployeeForm16", "Form16_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), cookieValue);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
         TempData["Success"] = "Something went wrong";
     }

     return RedirectToAction("EmployeeInvestmentDetailList");
     //return FileAsPDF(empSalaryDetail, "Partials/_EmployeeForm16", "Form16_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), cookieValue); 
 }
```

```
 var empInvestmentData = context.EmployeeInvestmentDetails.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.EmployeeId == Id);
 empSalaryDetail.PaidAmount = entity.Sum(x => x.PaidValue);
 empSalaryDetail.EPFAmount = entity.Sum(x => x.PaidValue );
```

[See 80C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGaJo.png)
[SEE amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnPN1.png)

i tried  empSalaryDetail.EPFAmount = entity.Sum(x => x.PaidValue - x.EPF.toDecimal() );
but after this its throwing error something went wrong
i am expecting total Paid amount - total amount from UI which i inserted

Comment: It is working for PaidAmount and not EPFAmount.  Everything you posted is the same for both.  Error may be in the code that is filling the form which you did not post.

Comment: You have made this more difficult on yourself by suppressing the error message. You need to know the details of the exception. Instead of some fixed string you should use ex.Message so you have a chance at debugging your code.

Comment: i have done that as well EPF is comming out as zero